# Timber & WPML string translation

Tags: wordpress, twig, wpml, timber

Hi I'm using Timber and what it used to be as simple as

```
_e('string', 'theme')
```

to translate strings with WPML, seems to not been working on Timber any idea on how to translate strings?

I have tried the following and nothing is working

```
{{ _e('string') }} & {{ _('string') }}

{{ _e('string', 'theme') }}

{{ function("icl_translate", 'theme', 'string_identifier', 'string) }}

{{ dump(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) }} // Doesn't return anything, so not an option either
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could trying starting from here: https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Comment: This is not related to either WPML or Timber... doesn't help me lot I think...

Comment: You should give a look to this discussion https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/468

Comment: Hey thanks, but I already check this out.. most of the examples above are from this place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes I use this;

```
{{ __('All items', 'theme') }}
```

And it's working perfectly.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the string that I had already on the theme, re-scan for strings and it worked. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick test and was able to get this to work....

Created files with a translation for `"thingy" ==> "foobar"` in `en_US.mo` and `en_US.po` in `wp-content/themes/mytheme/languages` from there...

#### single.php

```
$lang_dir = get_stylesheet_directory().'/languages';
load_theme_textdomain('mytheme', $lang_dir);
Timber::render("single.twig");
```

#### single.twig

```
I like {{ __('thingy', 'mytheme') }}
```

#### Output

```
I like foobar
```

Try replicating that to see if it works. At least at that point we can isolate things to WPML versus native translate stuff